# Syntax Error "Variable has already been declared"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This (simple) code seems to give me nightmares.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-source="ryedai">Ryedai</a>
<a href="#" data-source="alcea">Alcea</a>
<div class="formClass">
  <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-source]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var source = $(this).data('source');
    myeditFunction(source);
  });
  function myeditFunction(source) {
    if (source === 'ryedai') {
      $("#editor").load("https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/social_media_-_mastodon_ryedai-mastodon.social.html");
    } else if (source === 'alcea') {
      $("#editor").load("https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/social_media_-_mastodon_alcea-pbtodon.de.html");
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I can click any of the link(s) and it will load the element into the dom  no problem.
But the second time, it is raining "Syntax error - variable already declared" errors in the console.

How do I fix this ?

I don't understand why I cannot rewrite the element like this

Comment: Is there a script in the page you are loading?

Comment: I suppose, but if that were an issue, then that'd hinder the initial load also.. However that is a good suggestion. Edit: both the htmls actually do have a apiUrl. But isn't that constricted to the html each their own ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML document at `https://alcea-wisteria.de/PHP/social_media_-_mastodon_ryedai-mastodon.social.html` contains a `<script>` element.

That script declares a global `const` variable.

When you `load` the HTML document, that script is executed and creates that variable.

When you `load` it again, the script is executed again, and throws an error when it tries to recreate that constant.

---

As a couple of rules of thumb:

- Avoid using `load` to pull in entire HTML documents with their own scripts which pollute the DOM. Instead load minimum amounts of pure content (perhaps as HTML with `load` or perhaps as JSON which you then create a DOM from) and use [delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) for interactivity.
- Avoid using global variables. The simplest way to avoid them is to write your code as [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) where the top level scope is the module instead of global.

Comment: can you give an example of such "module" ? I want to really avoid constant variables. But I wasn't sure how. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html